# What to do in this situation?

Tags: support, edits

So if I meet a poor post, like this one:

[Organizing methods within classes in a simulation of a dice game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31332884/organizing-methods-within-classes-in-a-simulation-of-a-dice-game)

What should I do? I can't format the code without breaking the question. Should I flag as VLQ or leave it? Or edit it, leaving some funny indentation at certain parts?

Comment: Why not ask this on MSO? It is a code formatting question which should be answered there.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yeah but this applies anywhere. Any site with a similar situation can also have this apply

Comment: Hmmm ok now @PatrickHofman has cleaned it up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can resolve the issue just simply editing the code as you would like to. Note that OP, or anyone else, can revert your edit if they don't like it.

If your edit improves readability and help to get the question answered, why hesitate to edit it? As long as you don't invalidate it by changing the actual code (like removing brackets, etc), there is no harm.

Comment: So I leave some funny indentation but do my best to format it?

Comment: No, format it all the way as it is necessary to improve readability. See my edit to see how I would expect it to be edited.